# req.body is undefined - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

Here is my html:

```
<form action='/new'  method='POST' >
  <span>pool name: </span>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="hidden" name="imageSrcList" />
  <button type='submit' >Create new</button>
</form>
```

And here is the relevant JS:

```
var app = express()
app.use(fileUpload());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

---

```
app.post('/new', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.name);
  })
```

The console reads out:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I have tried with `console.log(req.body)` and this also is undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `body-parser` middleware which is necessary to have `req.body` set to a value. Express doesn't come with this by default and will need to be installed via NPM `npm i --save body-parser`

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Comment: perfect! thank you! I will up vote you in 5 minutes. thanks again!